# How can I access an object in a modal view

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter-bootstrap-3, pug

I have a game inside a canvas tag.  When I click on a game entity I want to open a modal and in the view, be able to access the clicked object's properties.

Here is the function that's called when I click the game entity:

```
function pause(player) {
  $('myModal').modal();
}
```

Here is the view where the modal is rendered:

```
#myModal.modal.fade(tabindex='-1', role='dialog', aria labelledby='myModalLabel', aria-hidden='true')
  .modal-dialog
     .modal-content
       .modal-header
         button.close(type='button', data-dismiss='modal', aria-label='Close')
          span(aria-hidden='true') &times;
        h4#myModalLabel.modal-title 
      .modal-body
        h5 Object Properties
        ul.list-group
          -// List all properties of the player object here
        form
          .form-group
            label.control-label(for='script-text') Text:
            input#script-text.form-control(type='text')
      .modal-footer
        button.btn.btn-primary.pull-left(type='button') Submit
        button.btn.btn-default(type='button', data-dismiss='modal') Cancel
```

How can I access the `player` object from within the view?  I'm sure there is a simple answer to this, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply write into `.modal-body` container after modal is opened:

```
function pause(player) {
    $('#myModal').modal().find('.modal-body').html(JSON.stringify(player));
}
```

Of course instead of JSON.stringify you might want to format object properties more nicely.

Comment: Thanks!  I knew there was an easy answer.